# Why does this AppleScript get an "AppleEvent handler failed" error on Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard?

Tags: email, applescript, osx-leopard

First, I know, Leopard is the old-fogey at this point, but it's the minimum I'd like to be able to support with this script, so please bear with me (it's not even possible under Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger due to a [bug w/Mail `redirect`/`forward`/`reply` bug I had uncovered long ago](http://www.makkintosshu.com/journal/mails-broken-replyredirectforward-applescript-support)).

I've been revisiting building an AppleScript to work in conjunction with [Topic Desk's `spamtrainer`](http://osx.topicdesk.com/content/view/37/58/), so it goes through a selection of messages in the Junk folder and attempts to redirect them to a specified mailbox. Here's what I have so far (note that the actual sending is commented out at the moment, more on that later):

```
(* Train Spam - Redirect (not forward) email from the Junk folder (which hasn't already been redirected or
 *             determined by the mail server to be spam) to an appropriate spam mailbox on the mail server.
 *             Developed to be used in conjunction w/spamtrainer on a Mac OS X Server mail server.
 * 
 * v0.1   2011-07-27 - Morgan Aldridge
 *                     Initial version.
 *)

using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages selectedMsgs in mailboxes selectedMailboxes
        tell application "Mail"
            -- configuration variables
            set junkPrefix to "***JUNK MAIL***"
            set junkRecipient to "junkmail@domain.tld"

            -- ensure that we're in the Junk mailbox
            -- (it'd be disasterous to accidentally redirect mail for training from another mailbox)
            if (count of selectedMailboxes) is 1 and (first item of selectedMailboxes) is junk mailbox then
                set selCount to (count of selectedMsgs)
                set redirectedCount to 0
                repeat with counter from 1 to selCount
                    set msg to item counter of selectedMsgs
                    -- if the subject doesn't start with junkPrefix and the message hasn't already been redirected, then redirect it
                    -- (otherwise, if it starts with junkPrefix, it means it was already detected as junk by the mail server)
                    -- (and, obviously, if it was already redirected, that was probably for the sake of junk training as well)
                    if subject of msg does not start with junkPrefix and not was redirected of msg then
                        set newRedirectMsg to redirect msg with opening window
                        tell newRedirectMsg
                            -- set the to recipient to that of the specified spam mailbox on the mail server
                        make new recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:junkRecipient}
                            -- remove any bcc or cc recipient (we don't want to be spamming anyone else in the process)
                            delete bcc recipients
                            delete cc recipients
                        end tell
                        -- actually send the message
                        -- send newRedirectMsg
                    else
                        display dialog "Oops, the message was already flagged as junk by the mail server or you've already redirected it!"
                    end if
                end repeat
            else
                display dialog "Oops, you're not in your Junk mailbox!"
            end if
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
-- this is required when _not_ running from the Script menu (e.g. Script Editor, FastScripts, etc.)
using terms from application "Mail"
    on run
        tell application "Mail" to set sel to selection
        tell application "Mail" to set selBox to selected mailboxes of message viewer 1
        tell me to perform mail action with messages (sel) in mailboxes (selBox)
    end run
end using terms from
```

When running it from `Script Editor.app` (so it goes through the `on run` and `tell me to`) and a small number of Junk messages select in Mail (this is under Mac OS X 10.5.8 Leopard), it seems to work for the first message (opening a new redirected message, w/to recipient set, and CC/BCC fields emptied), and the other redirected message windows open, but their To/CC/BCC fields are not updated and `Script Editor.app` pops up the dialog with the "Mail got an error: AppleEvent handler failed" error. The contents of the Event Log are as follows:

```
tell application "Mail"
    get selection
        {message id 464214 of mailbox "Junk", message id 464213 of mailbox "Junk", message id 464211 of mailbox "Junk"}
    get selected mailboxes of message viewer 1
        {junk mailbox}
    get junk mailbox
        junk mailbox
    get subject of message id 464214 of mailbox "Junk"
        ": Your Invitation Into a Global Directory"
    get was redirected of message id 464214 of mailbox "Junk"
        false
    redirect message id 464214 of mailbox "Junk" with opening window
        outgoing message id 400031520
    make new recipient at beginning of every to recipient of outgoing message id 400031520 with properties {address:"junkmail@domain.tld"}
        to recipient 1 of outgoing message id 400031520
    delete every bcc recipient of outgoing message id 400031520
    delete every cc recipient of outgoing message id 400031520
    get subject of message id 464213 of mailbox "Junk"
        "Nominate Your Favorite Products for the Community Choice Awards"
    get was redirected of message id 464213 of mailbox "Junk"
        false
    redirect message id 464213 of mailbox "Junk" with opening window
        outgoing message id 378471104
    make new recipient at beginning of every to recipient of outgoing message id 378471104 with properties {address:"junkmail@domain.tld"}
        "Mail got an error: AppleEvent handler failed."
```

So, clearly it seems like the failure is with setting the `to recipients` in all but the first message. Subsequent runs of the script without relaunching Mail result in failures on the first message as well.

The oddest part of this issue is that, when quitting mail after running the script, there's a hidden, blank window for *each* of the redirected messages (even the one that was successful) that pops up asking if you want to save changes or not. This sounds *very* similar to something noted in [this thread](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=110845), but I'm not sure what causes it.

So, what's causing this error and failure? How can I resolve it? And, for extra credit, why are the hidden, blank messages created and how can I prevent that from occurring?

Comment: Note that I am not able to reproduce this on 10.6. It works fine on my computer. On that note, nice script :)

Comment: Did you ever find out how to avoid the drafts (your "hidden windows") that pop up when quitting? I'm trying to fix the same issue for my script and can't find anything on this. Thanks!

Comment: @fastasleep Unfortunately, I did not.

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks fine to me.

If I were you, I would try running the script in another OS X account on the same computer, repair permissions, look at your logs (you've already done that, but it's still a good idea), run all relevant software updates, temporarily move your `~/Library/Mail` folder to eliminate it as a factor, etc. Tell me what happens, especially if it works again :)